# Actually mapping a y value and "..count.." in the same graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know that when people usually ask about mapping a y variable and using "..count.." at the same time, people correct them with the proper use of stat_bin or something.  I'm asking something slightly different.

I would like to put text on my graph that displays the value for "..count..".  I can do this with:

```
  stat_bin(aes(label=..count..),vjust=1, geom="text")
```

However, that makes the y value for each text label equal to the count. I would like to make the y value of each text label equal to the mean of that x value.  I'm graphing confidence intervals, with something like this:

```
d.logit_test %>%
ggplot(aes(x=AudioType,
         #y=score,
         color=Condition)) +
stat_summary(aes(y=score),
           fun.data="mean_cl_boot",
           geom="errorbar") +
stat_bin(aes(label=..count..),vjust=1, geom="text")
```

As it is now, the y values of the text completely screw up the plot. Is there any way of getting the "..count.." value from stat_bin, or giving it a different y value?

Thanks.

People have asked for sample data, and here it is:

```
d.logit_test <- data.frame(
score=c(-1,-0.25,0,0.25,1,-1,-0.25,0,0.25,1,1,1),
AudioType=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
Condition=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
)
d.logit_test %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=AudioType,
      #y=score,
      color=Condition)) +
   stat_summary(aes(y=score),
      fun.data="mean_cl_boot",
      geom="errorbar") +
   stat_bin(aes(label=..count..),vjust=1, geom="text")
```

I want the "5" and "7" to have y values so that they appear at the mean value of each condition.

Comment: It would be nice to have a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, then it would actually be a fairly good question. So please provide sample data (dput). Meanwhile: have you tried giving an y value in stat_bin? Like `stat_bin(aes(y= XXX, label=..count..)`?

Comment: I posted the sample data above.  When I do: `stat_bin(aes(y=score,label=..count..))`, I get: `Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.`